Text rendered in browser has a larger "A" letter than in design program


Hi,
I have a problem in that the capital A of the font Gentium Plus (Google font) is rendered slightly (but impactful) higher size in the browser compared to Figma. It goes some 2 pixels above the other letters. I have demonstrated this in the attached image.

Same font-size and line-height in both examples (1.6rem and 23px).
I have html { font-size: 10px; }
It seems like in the browser, when choosing 1.8rem (18px) and 1.9rem (19px), the font looks normal, like in Figma. Please see second attached image.

If anyone can think of why this is, it would be greatly appreciated, since I would like to use this very font.

You can't fix it. This difference is related to the rendering engines and how they interpret "Hinting" instructions  which are used to adjust the rendering to match the screens pixel grid. The result will also look different in Firefox, Chromium or Safari. The best you can do is to tweak the font size or choose another font that's less prone to this issue

What browsers are you using? In my FF the issue reproduces with font-size < 10px

herrstrietzel: Thanks for your input. Kosh: I am using Firefox. Hm, that's interesting.

It also reproduces with your font-size @ 110% zoom.

As @herrstrietzel suggested, the best option would be to consider analternative fonts.
If you prefer using Gentium Plus, the only way comes to mind is to set bigger font-size and scale it down using perspective and transform: translateZ(). Legibility may suffer though and other issues may rise.
Note: simple transform:scale() does not give an acceptable result.


html {
  font: 700 10px/1.4375 "Gentium Plus", serif;
}

section {
  perspective: 100px;
  perspective-origin: 0 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 23px;
}

p.scaled {
  font-size: 3rem;
  transform: translateZ(-87px);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gentium+Plus:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<section>
  <p>AVAILABLE ARTWORKS</p>
  <p class="scaled">AVAILABLE ARTWORKS</p>
</section>



